# Aligning imagery in ERDAS Imagine?

Tags: erdas-imagine

I have two Imagine files that I need to mosaic. When I added these two in Erdas Imagine, there is a black gap between them, for example, they are not properly aligned. I know very little bit about georeferencing, projection, or coordinate system, but I don't understand them very well.

Can you please explain me to understand how to align those two Imagery ?

[image: two img files misaligned]
I tried to use the "MosaicPro" tool in Erdas Imagine and this can mosaic two imagine files to create seamless single into one Imagery file and how to "stitch" with the the right portion and the left portion?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include a screenshot? Is the black gap just in between the images or is it surrounding the entire image?

Comment: @Fezter, Thanks for your suggestion! the gap is just between images, I want to remove that gap, is this because the wrong coordination of the right partion ?

Comment: Does the gap move when you change the order of the images? What happens if you try to make No Data pixels transparent (sorry, I don't know Erdas software very well)

Comment: Also, when you use the Mosaic tool, ensure you Compute Active Area when you import the images.  See [this video](http://community.hexagongeospatial.com/t5/ERDAS-IMAGINE/Create-a-Mosaic-using-ERDAS-IMAGINE-MosaicPro/ta-p/2261)

Answer (score -2):

At last, we found that those two portions are not aligned is because a third portion is found and should be placed between them.